# Mit einem Messer angegriffen, bin ich nach Hause gegangen (Kommas)

Tags: punctuation

Können Sie mir bitte sagen, ob man diese Kommas setzen soll oder nicht?

1. Mit einem Messer **angegriffen, bin** ich nach Hause gegangen.
2. Von mir **geschnitten, sind** die Wassermelonenstücke von meinen Freunden gegessen.
3. Von den Jungen **erschrocken, hat** das Kätzchen sie böse geknabbert.
4. Von dem Kätzchen **verschlungen, gingen** sie zum Arzt.

Comment: Woher stammen die Sätze? Ob Komma oder nicht, sie sind alle falsch.

Comment: @userunknown: Satz 1 ist richtig, bei Satz 2 fehlt das "worden" am Ende, Satz 3 und 4 sind grammatikalisch korekt, aber semantisch sinnlos.

Comment: @bakunin: Und ich hielt die Semantik für eine Teilmenge der Grammatik.Satz 2 könnte alternativ durch "wurden" statt "sind" geheilt werden.

Comment: @userunknown: daß Semantik eben keine Teilmenge der Grammatik ist (und es deshalb möglich ist, grammatikalisch korrekte Sätze zu bilden, die völliger Unfug sind), sagt Noam Chomsky: "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously."

Comment: Wikipedia@Grammatik: Grammatik ist zum einen der Begriff für ein Wissensgebiet, das Gegenstand der „Grammatiktheorie“ ist, also das sprachliche System selbst, in seiner abstrakten Form. In der Sprachwissenschaft umfasst dieser Begriff alle Bereiche, in denen die Gliederung sprachlicher Einheiten untersucht wird, also die Formenlehre von Wörtern (d. h. die Morphologie), den Bau von Sätzen (Syntax), die Lautlehre (Phonologie) sowie die Bedeutungslehre (Semantik), soweit sie sich auf Regeln zum Aufbau von sprachlicher Bedeutung bezieht.

Answer (score 4):

[Das Komma nach einer solchen Partizipialgruppe ist optional.](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komma-partizip) Das ist aber im Deutschen keine sehr gebräuchliche Konstruktion. Außerdem ergeben die Beispiele nur wenig Sinn. Kätzchen wird es nicht gelingen, Menschen zu verschlingen, und wer verschlungen wurde, kann auch nicht mehr zum Arzt gehen.

Comment: Satz 2 ist falsch, weil "sind ... gegessen" hier nicht stimmt. Das müßte Passiv sein, d.h. "sind ... gegessen *worden*".